# What does $d=d^h+d^v$ mean?

Tags: homological-algebra

When one defines $\text{Tot}(C) = \text{Tot}^{П}(C)$ a total complex one usually writes "the formula $d=d^h+d^v$ defines map $d$: $\text{Tot}^{П}(C)_n \rightarrow \text{Tot}^{П}(C)_{n-1}$". How one gets this map $d$? (What does $d=d^h+d^v$ mean exactly?)

Comment: You are working with a bigraded complex $C^{\bullet,\bullet}$ with the "horizontal" $d^h$ and "vertical" $d^v$ when you lay it out in 2D.